# Post with WebRequest

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am trying to post to google so I can log into Google Reader and download subscription list, but I am unable to find a way to post to google in the windows 7 phone sdk, does anyone have an example on how to do this?

*Edit: Sorry wasn't very clear I am trying use the POST method, to submit an email and password to google login and retrieve a sid. I have used WebClient and HttpWebRequest but all the examples I have seen to send post data, the api calls are not in the windows 7 phone sdk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using [RESTSharp](http://restsharp.org/) for your Windows Phone 7 project? The latest release supports Windows Phone 7 and I have had no issues working with popular REST APIs with it. In your particular case where you are trying to use the Google Reader API, [this article](http://lukencode.com/2010/08/04/rest-web-services-in-windows-phone-7/) by Luke Lowry can possibly help.

Answer (score 18):

I don't know anything about the Google API you're trying to use, but if all you need is to send a POST request, you can certainly do that with `WebClient` or `HttpWebRequest`. With `WebClient`, you can use either `WebClient.OpenWriteAsync()` or `WebClient.UploadStringAsync()`, the documentation is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0f69eh%28v=VS.95%29.aspx

With `HttpWebRequest`, you'll need to set the `Method` property to `"POST"`. Here's a basic example:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(/* your_google_url */)) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "POST";
request.BeginGetRequestStream(ar =>
{
    var requestStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(ar);
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(requestStream))
    {
        // Write the body of your request here
    }

    request.BeginGetResponse(a =>
    {
        var response = request.EndGetResponse(a);
        var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            // Parse the response message here
        }

    }, null);

}, null);
```

The `WebClient` class may be easier to use, but is less customizable. For instance, I haven't seen a way to be able to attach cookies to `WebClient` requests, or a way to set the Content-Type header when using `WebClient`.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you've already used, but have you tried WebClient?

```
WebClient web = new WebClient();
web.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
{
    if (e.Error == null)
        CodeHereToHandleSuccess();
    else
        CodeHereToHandleError(e.Error);
};
web.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(theURLYoureTryingToUse));
```

There's also [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest(VS.95).aspx) to look at too, that might work for what you're doing.

Edit: As for your "POST" edit, webclient lets you do post:

```
        web.OpenWriteAsync(new Uri(theURLYoureTryingToUse), "POST");
```

you also then have to add an OpenWriteCompleted handler.

not sure exactly what you're doing, so you'll need to add more info to your question.