# Send image in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, post, httprequest

I need to send an image(jpeg,png,etc) to server with parameter "access_token" and "photo"(image that I need to send).

```
..if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK) {
                BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
                image.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
                //  foto.Source = image;
                Byte[] byteArray;
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
                    WriteableBitmap btmMap = new WriteableBitmap(image);

                    // write an image into the stream
                    System.Windows.Media.Imaging.Extensions.SaveJpeg(btmMap, ms, image.PixelWidth, image.PixelHeight, 0, 100);

                    byteArray = ms.ToArray();
                }
((App)Application.Current).get_data(uploadServer + "?photo=" + *HOW I CAN SEND BYTE ARRAY?* + "&access_token=" + ((App)Application.Current).access_token
```

//

```
public void get_data(string url,Action<string> qw) {
            try {
                var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
                    new Uri(url));
                request.BeginGetResponse(r => {
                    var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)r.AsyncState;
                    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.EndGetResponse(r);
                    HttpStatusCode st = httpResponse.StatusCode;
                    if (st == HttpStatusCode.NotFound) {
                        ToastPrompt toast = new ToastPrompt();
                        toast.TextOrientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Vertical;
                        toast.Message = "Ошибка соединения с сервером";
                        toast.MillisecondsUntilHidden = 2000;
                        toast.Show();
                    } else
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream())) {
                            var response = reader.ReadToEnd();
                            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
                                qw(response);
                            }));

                        }
                }, request);
            } catch (WebException e) { }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WP7 - POST form with an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622900/wp7-post-form-with-an-image)

```
Dictionary<string, object> data = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                    {
                    {"photo", byteArray},
                    };
                    PostSubmitter post = new PostSubmitter() { url = uploadServer, parameters = data };
                    post.Submit();
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "GET" an image to a URL (you are trying to post data into the URL which you *can't*), you need to "POST" your image using the `OutputStream` of your POST request.

Comment: Well, you *can*, but it has to be encoded in a query string parameter or cookie. (Cookies can be generated client-side).

Comment: yes but I think they have a size limit (e.g. 8K or something), which is not suitable (and not intended) for sending images, but yes technically it IS possible

Comment: function "get_data" is making post request.The server supports receiving images.How I can do it(like you say) with OutputStream ?

Comment: well, you shouldn't be writing to the URL query string so first delete that part (to avoid further confusion). second, I don't know which library this you are using.. it's not the standard web client of .NET framework... is it facebook or something?

Comment: I'm using API of site like facebook, not facebook. I need to send an image(jpg,png,gif) to the server like "server_url?photo=my_photo&access_token=key".

Comment: can you please post a link to the API documentation

Comment: you first need to obtain a url using that `getPhotoUploadServer` method, and post tha image to that URL and after posting that, then you need to run your original method.

Comment: I've already done it. I can't send image('photo') to the server.