# How to upload and send file and string data to server from windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I need to send file to server along with a xml string from windows phone.

below is the server side IhttpHandler code.

Now please give me some code example for windows phone that 1 big file can upload to server and also a xml or any string by POST?

below the server side code

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Test" %>

using System;
using System.Web;

using System.IO;


public class Test : IHttpHandler {

public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";



    context.Response.Write(AddSurveyMediaWithFile(context.Request.Files[0] , context.Request["MediaDataXML"].ToString()));

}

public bool IsReusable {
    get {
        return false;
    }
}

public string ShowMessage(string msg)
{
    return msg;
}

public String AddSurveyMediaWithFile(HttpPostedFile uploadedFile, string MediaDataXML)
{



    try
    {
        Survey.AddDataMediaXMLCheck(MediaDataXML, "Media");


        string FilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../MediaFiles/");
        AttributeValue objAttributeValue = ParseValue(MediaDataXML);
        objAttributeValue.Value = objAttributeValue.Value;
        OrganizationUnitLicense objLicense = OrganizationUnitLicense.ValidateFilesize(objAttributeValue.UserWorkUnitSurveyID);

        if (objAttributeValue.Filesize > 0)
        {


            if (objLicense.Space > 0)
            {

                if ((objLicense.TotalFilesize + objAttributeValue.Filesize) <= (objLicense.Space * 1024 * 1024))
                {
                    string msg = Survey.AddSurveyData(MediaDataXML);

                    if (msg == Enumerators.SQLReturn.SUCCESS.ToString())
                    {
                        if (File.Exists(FilePath + objAttributeValue.Value))
                            File.Delete(FilePath + objAttributeValue.Value);


                        uploadedFile.SaveAs(FilePath + objAttributeValue.Value);



                        return Enumerators.SQLReturn.SUCCESS.ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return msg;
                    }

                }
                else
                {

                    return "FILESIZE_" + Enumerators.SQLReturn.LIMIT_NOT_EXIST.ToString();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                string msg = Survey.AddSurveyData(MediaDataXML);

                if (msg == Enumerators.SQLReturn.SUCCESS.ToString())
                {
                    if (File.Exists(FilePath + objAttributeValue.Value))
                        File.Delete(FilePath + objAttributeValue.Value);

                    uploadedFile.SaveAs(FilePath + objAttributeValue.Value);


                    return Enumerators.SQLReturn.SUCCESS.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    return msg;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return "FILESIZE_ZERO";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {



        return ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace; //Enumerators.SQLReturn.ERROR.ToString();
    }
}

private AttributeValue ParseValue(string MediaDataXML)
{
    .....    //to do section
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read your code but I'll answer your question anyways.

**To upload a string data to server :**

```
Public Sub UploadFile(xmlPath As String, type As String)
    Try
        Dim webClient As New WebClient()
        webClient.Headers(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType) = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        Dim uri = New Uri(xmlPath, UriKind.Absolute)
        Dim postData As New StringBuilder()
        postData.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", "YOUR_PARAMETER_HERE", "")

        webClient.Headers(HttpRequestHeader.ContentLength) = postData.Length.ToString()
        AddHandler webClient.UploadStringCompleted, AddressOf webClient_UploadStringCompleted
        webClient.UploadStringAsync(uri, "POST", postData.ToString())
    Catch ex As Exception
        LogError(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

**Then you need to handle the response here :**

```
 Private Sub webClient_UploadStringCompleted(sender As Object, e As UploadStringCompletedEventArgs)
        Try
            Dim jsonString = e.Result
            //PUT YOUR OWN CODE HERE
        Catch ex As Exception
            LogError(ex)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

As for uploading files, I recommend you  read this answer : [WP7 - POST form with an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622900/wp7-post-form-with-an-image)