# post data in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone

I would like to POST data from my Windows Phone to a webpage that I created myself. The webpage will process the data and display any results.

After I POST the data, how I am able to navigate to the webpage with the posted data? (Example to www.test.com/#name=joe in the case it was GET)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible approach is to dynamically create an HTML page that performs the POST request and load it into the web browser control. The resulting web page will then nicely be displayed in the control.

The HTML page could look like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Faceless</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitForm() {
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }
</script>
  </head>
  <body onload="submitForm();">
    <form method="POST" action="http://www.server.com/service.php">
      <input type="hidden" name="name" value="Robert">
      <input type="hidden" name="score" value="200">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can load it into a web browser control with [NavigateToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.navigatetostring%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method.

Don't forget to enable JavaScript:

```
<phone:WebBrowser Name="webBrowser1" IsScriptEnabled="True" />
```

Comment: Thanks I overlooked this method, it makes more sense this way

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking up .net `Web Requests` and the .net web [client class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)?

If your site is coded using PHP, you can send a http post request to the page (try avoid using a GET request for security reasons), and then do the necessary processing you need to do with the data.

Maybe this similar question will be of use to you:

[Post with WebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562206/post-with-webrequest)

Comment: I can't see how this answer would help to display the resulting HTML page.

Comment: @Codo it is true your answer makes more sense. thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

You could do 2 things
1. Send a Http Web Request of type POST. With this you have more control over the other approaches.
1. Once you get the response, load the dynamic html page in a webview(The dynamic page will be generated at the server side).